# Merging Data frames based on row values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I have 2 dataframes of unequal lengths. df1 is a data frame with data in 3 columns and 6 rows

```
   Col A  Col B   Col C
     1      2       3
     2      3       4
     3      4       5
     4      5       6
     5      6       7
     8      9      10
```

df2 is another file with data in 3 columns and 3 rows

```
    Col A   Col B   Col C
      4       5       9
      7       8      11
      9      10      13
```

I want to merge df1 and df2 such that if col 2 and col 3 in df1 and col 1 and col 2 in df2 are equal then result is a data frame of 4 columns while other rows are dropped

**Expected Result**

```
   Col A  Col B  Col C Col D
    3      4      5     9
    8      9     10     13
```

**Code**

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  df1 = pd.DataFrame ({'colA': ['4', '7', '9'],
                       'colB': ['5', '8', '10'],
                       'colC': ['9', '11', '13']},
                        index=[0, 1, 2])


  df2 = pd.DataFrame ({'colA': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '8'],
                       'colB': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '9'],
                       'colC': ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '10']},
                        index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

  new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='left', left_on =['df1_colB','colC'], 
                                           right_on = ['df2_colA','colB'])

  print(new_df)
```

The program

```
  Exception has occurred: KeyError
```

Are there any alternative methods to do this using csv?

Comment: what you put in `left_on` should be your column names so `colB` instead of `df1_colB`

Comment: It gets me all the values other than those in the col A in the expected result.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about how you wanna merge them. Could you add a little bit more details? meanwhile, by col 1.. do you actually me col A?

Comment: I guess, what I want the program to do can be stated as follows:                     
When comparing rows in df1 and df2, if col B and col C of a row in df1 equals col A and col B of a row in df2 then create a new dataframe (new_df) with col C from df2 added as colD in df1

Answer (score 1):

Try merge `df2` with `df1` having `rename` column names to match 2 columns in `df2`

```
df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'colA': 'colB', 'colB': 'colC', 'colC':'colD'}))

Out[14]:
  colA colB colC colD
0    3    4    5    9
1    8    9   10   13
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mix up the order of your dataframes. Please use this code, it is not exactly you need but close:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df2, df1,  how='inner', left_on =['colB','colC'], 
                                           right_on = ['colA','colB'])
```